# Incompatible Qt4 versions

Tags: pyqt4, enthought

I get the following error when I try to run a script from Canopy:

> Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40807) with this library
>   (version 0x40806)

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome. I used Qt Designer to create the form code. I ran Synaptic and I only see one version of the QT library installed.

I found https://askubuntu.com/questions/534415/cannot-mix-incompatible-qt-library and a couple of other things on forums, but can't make sense of what I have found.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have now tested this on my work Windows installation. I am using the same version of Canopy on both Windows and Linux, and the script works on Windows.

Comment: Also, I tried running from the commandline rather than the Canopy IDE and it works fine, so I guess it must be a configuration thing in Canopy.